# Angular service with rxjs timer... Need subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'd like to implement a global dropdown timeout in which the user can mouse out of a dropdown but then back into it in order to prevent it from vanishing. I'm using a service for this but I'm not sure how to implement the timer.

The Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DropTimerService {
  dropHide$ = new Observable();

  constructor() { }

  startTimer(): void {
    console.log('starting the timer')
    this.dropHide$ = timer(3000);
  }

  stopTimer(): void {
    console.log('stopping the timer')
    this.dropHide$ = new Observable();
  }
}
```

The start and stop functions are running; the console logs are reporting correctly, but the subscription to the observable isn't firing.

```js
this.dropSub = this.dropTimer.dropHide$.subscribe(event => {
  console.log(event)
  this.dropClass = '';
})
```

I'm thinking I need a `Subject` and to `.next` the subject on a timer, but I'm not sure. I also need to stop the timer when the user mouses back into the dropdown, and would like to also be able to make the timer expire immediately on command (when the user opens a different dropdown, any others should get a signal to close).

I feel like I could do this with some `setTimeout`s that pump a `Subject`'s `.next` but I also feel that there's probably a pure rxjs way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the above-written service code is, that the `dropHide$` member variable will be assigned to new `Observable` instances. If it gets a new instance, the previous subscription gets lost. This is why the following happens:

1. The `dropHide$` gets a default `Observable` instance with `dropHide$ = new Observable();`.
2. In the component with `subscribe` we subscribe to its events.
3. When `startTimer()` is called `this.dropHide$ = timer(3000);` assignes a new insance to `dropHide$` so the callback of the previous `subscribe` will be never called.
4. The newly instantiated `Observable` has no subscription and as an `Observable` is lazy, the event never fires.

To fix this I propose a solution.
In the `service` we store a `Subscription` and subscribe to it when the timer needs to be started. The subscribe gets a callback function that can be called when the timer is done. If the timer is canceled we simply unsubscribe from the `Subscription`. This way the `service` code looks following:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription, timer } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class DropTimerService {
  private timerSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {}

  startTimer(timerDone: Function) {
    console.log("Starting the timer");
    this.timerSubscription = timer(3000).subscribe(event => {
      timerDone();
    });
  }

  stopTimer(): void {
    console.log("Timer stopped");
    this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

A sample component template:

```
<p>
    Use the buttons to start/cancel the timer.
</p>
<button (click)="onStartClick()">Start</button> 
<button (click)="onStopClick()">Cancel</button>
```

And the component code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { DropTimerService } from "./drop-timer.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  constructor(private dropTimerService: DropTimerService) {}

  onStartClick() {
    function TimerFinishedCallback() {
      console.log("Timer finished!");
    }
    this.dropTimerService.startTimer(TimerFinishedCallback);
  }

  onStopClick() {
    this.dropTimerService.stopTimer();
  }
}
```

To test it and play around with it here is the `stackblitz` code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kamee1?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: That's almost what I need, but it lacks the ability to close all other dropdowns when I open a new one. Currently, if I open a new one, the older ones that didn't expire stay open and never close until I mouse into and out of them. This is why I assumed I'd need a subject to subscribe to, to let the dropdowns know when they should be closing.

Comment: ^ Solved this by adding a subject to the service just to close all on each tick.